# List visual studio 2015 extensions as text export

Tags: visual-studio

If I go to visual studio help -> about there is a nice button to export information about what is installed as part of Visual studio, but it seems to exclude most of what is listed under tools -> extensions and updates.

[image]

I'm looking for a way to export a text list of the items under extensions and updates, but I don't really see a way through the UI and my googling hasn't turned up any console commands yet. I could just be misunderstanding some other part of how this is configured or displayed if the "copy info" output really is all of the extensions installed.

For instance, the items pictured don't seem to be in the about export, but have an option to uninstall.

[image]

Does anyone know a way to export this list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following C# command for [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) to copy the list of extensions to the clipboard:

(References: Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager)

```
public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
    {
        System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider = package as System.IServiceProvider;
        Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.IVsExtensionManager em =
           (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.IVsExtensionManager)serviceProvider.GetService(
                typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SVsExtensionManager));

        string result = "";
        foreach(Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.IInstalledExtension i in em.GetInstalledExtensions())
        {
            Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.IExtensionHeader h = i.Header;
            if (!h.SystemComponent)
                result += h.Name + " (by " + h.Author + ") v" + h.Version + " " + h.MoreInfoUrl + System.Environment.NewLine;
        }
        System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText(result);
    }
}
```

The result looks like:

```
Tabs Studio (by Vlasov Studio) v3.7.0 https://tabsstudio.com/
Visual Studio Extensions for Windows Library for JavaScript (by Microsoft) v1.0.9651.40228 http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=250992
Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows 8.1 (by Microsoft Advertising) v8.1.30809.0 http://www.windowsadvertising.com/
Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows Phone 8.1 XAML (by Microsoft Advertising) v8.1.40427.0 http://www.windowsadvertising.com/
```

Comment: Hi Sergey, thanks for the help. And that looks like it would do it, but I'm not  sure it is entirely appropriate to post your own paid extension here as the answer. At any rate I'm looking for a method to list these without a further extension.